# Which codec do I use for low latency video streaming with VLC?

Tags: debian, vlc-media-player, streaming, codec

I'm looking for a way to stream a webcam video with as low latency as possible.
Quality and resolution are far less important.

This is the command I'm currently using is:

```
cvlc -vvv v4l2:///dev/video0 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=800,acodec=none}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}'
```

It works but has a 2000ms delay over a LAN which is too high.
I'm happy to sacrifice resolution or quality to reduce the delay.

VLC has a list of [codecs](https://wiki.videolan.org/Codec/) but I don't want to spend hours trying to install them if they end up been slow.

Comment: Honestly, if you're looking for low latency I would move away from VLC.  In my experience its not possible to get low latency video from VLC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce latency on FFmpeg video streaming?](https://superuser.com/questions/726393/how-to-reduce-latency-on-ffmpeg-video-streaming)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latency is a very problem mainly when using audio capture synchronization with the video online. For me works with the [theo codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theora), I am using this codec to control the resolution of transmission the implementation of this codec is native almost all compilations of VLC. In your case, you can set using this form:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :v4l2-standard= :live-caching=1000 :sout="#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=XXX,fps=30,scale=Y.Y}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:554/test}"
```

where XXX is the resolution and Y.Y is the scale, example:

```
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 :v4l2-standard= :live-caching=1000 :sout="#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=300,fps=30,scale=0.2}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:554/test}"
```

Source: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=101547

Comment: Congrats on your accepted answer and welcome to Super User!